# Simplify an equation in Matlab (MuPAD)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

I have the following equation and want to simplify it using Matlab's MuPAD.

[image]

So, I used this in MuPAD:

```
Simplify(Gb = Gm*((2*(Gd+t)+3*Gm+3*P*(Gd+t-Gm))/(2*(Gd+t)+3*Gm-2*P*(Gd+t-Gm))))
```

and I get this:

```
Gb*(3*Gm + 2*Gd + 2*t - 2*P*(Gd - Gm + t)) = Gm*(3*Gm + 2*Gd + 2*t + 3*P*(Gd - Gm + t)) and 3*Gm + 2*Gd + 2*t <> 2*P*(Gd - Gm + t)
```

I cannot understand the first and second part (after "and"), what are these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MuPAD's documentation, the relational operator [`<>` denotes inequality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/_unequal.html), i.e., the left- and right-hand side are not equal. In other words, the simplification (before "and") is only valid if `3*Gm + 2*Gd + 2*t` is not equal to `2*P*(Gd - Gm + t)`. This is the same thing as requiring that the denominator of the original expression not be zero (which would make it undefined).

Note that in MuPAD for Matlab R2015b, the `<>` operator is displayed as `≠` and "and" is rendered as `∧` ([logical and](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/and.html)):

[image: MuPAD output]